# SwiftUI using NSSharingServicePicker in MacOS

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I am trying to use a Share function inside my MacOS app in SwiftUI. I am having a URL to a file, which I want to share. It can be images/ documents and much more.

I found `NSSharingServicePicker` for MacOS and would like to use it. However, I am struggeling to use it in SwiftUI.

Following the documentation, I am creating it like this:

```
let shareItems = [...]

let sharingPicker : NSSharingServicePicker = NSSharingServicePicker.init(items: shareItems as [Any])

sharingPicker.show(relativeTo: NSZeroRect, of:shareView, preferredEdge: .minY)
```

My problem is in that `show()` method. I need to set a NSRect, where I can use NSZeroRect.. but I am struggeling with `of:` parameter. It requires a NSView. How can I convert my current view as NSView and use it that way. Or can I use my `Button` as `NSView()`. I am struggling with that approach.

Another option would be to use a `NSViewRepresentable`. But should I just create a NSView and use it for that method.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is minimal working demo example

[image: demo]

```
struct SharingsPicker: NSViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    var sharingItems: [Any] = []

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        let view = NSView()
        return view
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) {
        if isPresented {
            let picker = NSSharingServicePicker(items: sharingItems)
            picker.delegate = context.coordinator

            // !! MUST BE CALLED IN ASYNC, otherwise blocks update
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                picker.show(relativeTo: .zero, of: nsView, preferredEdge: .minY)
            }
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(owner: self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, NSSharingServicePickerDelegate {
        let owner: SharingsPicker

        init(owner: SharingsPicker) {
            self.owner = owner
        }

        func sharingServicePicker(_ sharingServicePicker: NSSharingServicePicker, didChoose service: NSSharingService?) {

            // do here whatever more needed here with selected service

            sharingServicePicker.delegate = nil   // << cleanup
            self.owner.isPresented = false        // << dismiss
        }
    }
}
```

Demo of usage:

```
struct TestSharingService: View {
    @State private var showPicker = false
    var body: some View {
        Button("Share") {
            self.showPicker = true
        }
        .background(SharingsPicker(isPresented: $showPicker, sharingItems: ["Message"]))
    }
}
```

Comment: Works great :) Thank you so much.. do you know by the way, if there is also the Open with.. context menu like in Finder available?

Comment: @davidev Did you find a way to do so?

Comment: @Asperi Do you have code for Mac Catalyst?

Comment: @davidev You would need to build your own context menu and provide the following function with the URL of the files you wish to open and the URL of the app you wish to launch. NSWorkspace.shared.open(fileUrlArray, withApplicationAt: appUrl, configuration:NSWorkspace.OpenConfiguration())

Answer (score 0):

Another option without using `NSViewRepresentable` is:

```
extension NSSharingService {
    static func submenu(text: String) -> some View {
        return Menu(
            content: {
                ForEach(items, id: \.title) { item in
                    Button(action: { item.perform(withItems: [text]) }) {
                        Image(nsImage: item.image)
                        Text(item.title)
                    }
                }
            },
            label: {
                Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
            }
        )
    }
}
```

You lose things like the "more" menu item or recent recipients. But in my opinion it's more than enough, simple and pure SwiftUI.

Comment: Almost there. Missing items

Answer (score 0):

As of macOS 13+ you can use the SwiftUI-native [`ShareLink`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/sharelink):

```
ShareLink(item: URL(string: "https://developer.apple.com/xcode/swiftui/")!) {
    Label("Share", image: "MyCustomShareIcon")
}
```

In typical SwiftUI fashion it works quite simple, but I also couldn’t figure out yet how to add custom `NSSharingService` like actions to this. Check out [my question on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78139134/swiftui-sharelink-with-custom-actions) for more information.