# SwiftUI ShareLink with custom actions

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui, ios-sharesheet, swiftui-sharelink

Currently, I’m using a `ShareLink` to display the standard share sheet in my app. Now, **I’d like to display actions inside the share sheet that perform a custom action like the following example.**

With UIKit this was done via a `UIActivity` object inside the `UIActivityViewController`.
In AppKit via a `NSSharingService` object inside the `NSSharingServicePicker`.

Is that possible with the `ShareLink` or do I have to bridge to UIKit/AppKit for this?

[image: macOS share sheet with custom actions at the bottom]